Which self-homeomorphisms preserve measure on a torus?
Which self homeomorphisms preserve measure on a torus.

Have you tried adapting the solution given by Iosif Pinelis to the 1-dimensional case that you already asked? https://mathoverflow.net/a/483471/

@YemonChoi I believe the flow generated by any solenoidal vector field should preserve measure, so there should be many examples (unlike the case in one-dimension).

What do you mean by a "continue automorphism"? This does not parse even on the syntax level. It is a general fact that the group of measure preserving diffeomorphisms is infinite-dimensional for every nonempty manifold of dimension $>1$ and any smooth measure. You can read Banyaga's book to learn more about such groups.

@MoisheKohan "continue" could be French and mean continuous (then it makes sense on the syntax level)

@VilleSalo: Maybe, but a "continuous automorphism" is very unclear mathematically speaking.

I don't disagree. Just I read a lot of Frenglish and to me this parsed very easily.

The word "automorphism" by itself is meaningless. You have to specify the structure which your map preserves. For instance, I can regard the torus as an abstract abelian group and talk about automorphisms of this group. Or I can regard the torus as a complex manifold, then automorphisms will be biholomorphic self-maps. Or I can regard the torus as a topological manifold, then automorphisms will be self-homeomorphisms.

Then it is even worse and you are asking if a measure-preserving homeomorphism is a composition of a rotation with a self-homeomorphism.

@MoisheKohan anyway it is clear what affine is, so what is meant by "automorphism", which is not central in the question, is clear here (for the torus $T^n$, this is $GL_n(Z)$). The question is still vague. If OP wants to know whether every such thing is affine, the answer is yes for $n=1$ and no for $n\ge 2$ (easy fact which was already addressed in comments), and otherwise "which self-homeos..." is quite open-ended.

Thanks @GabeK (and others) for correcting my lazy guess/misunderstanding.

As a simple example, if you take any divergence-free vector field, the flow generated by this vector field is incompressible, so preserves measures.
In fact, there are a huge number of measure preserving diffeomorphisms of the torus, so many that they cannot be classified.

It is very easy to construct many measure-preserving homeomorphisms which are piecewise affine.
I illustrate this with an example (easily modifiable
and generalizable ad nauseam) involving the standard torus
$\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$: Consider the piecewise linear map defined by
$(x,y)\longmapsto (x,y)$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$ and
$0\leq y\leq 1/2$ and by
$(x,y)\longmapsto (x+2y-1,y)$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$ and
$1/2\leq y\leq 1$.
